# Add element to array with condition

Tags: php

I have a foreach statement with an if statement at his top then a switch statement

```
<?php
foreach(self::CRITS as $crit){
    if( $crit == 'some condition') {
     $myVar = "size => 10";
    }

    switch($crit) {
        case1:
            $agg[$crit] = [
                "terms" => [
                    "field" => $crit
                    $myVar
                ]
            ];
            // expected if $crit == 'some condition' true
            //$agg[$crit] = [
            //    "terms" => [
            //        "field" => $crit
            //        "size" => 10
            //    ]
            //];
            // expected if $crit == 'some condition' false
            //$agg[$crit] = [
            //    "terms" => [
            //        "field" => $crit
            //    ]
            //];

        break;
        // more cases with same behavior

    }
}
```

According to the IF statement I want add `$myVar` as a new key/value pair to `$agg[$crit]["terms"]`.

I can do it in each case of my switch statement like

```
case1:
$agg[$crit] = [
    "terms" => [
        "field" => $crit
    ]
];

if($crit == 'some condition') {
    $agg[$crit]["terms"]["size"] = 10;
}
break;
```

but the IF statement will be duplicate.

There is a way in PHP to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunetly it seems impossible to be done that way.

So I figured out with a quite simple workaround and use of array_filter

```
<?php
foreach(self::CRITS as $crit){
    $condition = ( $crit === 'some condition' ? true : false);

    switch($crit) {
        case1:
           $agg[$crit] = [
               "terms" => array_filter([
                   "field" => $crit
                   "size" => ($condition ? $size[$crit] : NULL)
            ],function($v){
                return $v !== NULL;
            })
        ];
        break;
        // more cases with same behavior
    }
}
```

array filter will remove all size fields with value of NULL

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
if( $crit == 'some condition') {
    $myKey = 'size';
    $myValue = 10;
}

$agg[$crit] = [
    "terms" => [
        "field" => $crit,
        $myKey => $myValue,
    ]
]
```

Comment: what if $crit == 'some condition' returns false ? I guess json_encode on this array will not working right ?

Comment: Additionally check if `$myKey` and `$myValue` are not empty.

Comment: You should never use ==, always ===